# Is the product of $L^1$ functions $L^1$?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Is the product of two $L^1$ functions always $L^1$, and if it's not the case do you have a counter example ? Thank you 
By $L^1$ i mean functions that are integrable in the sens of Lebesgue.

Answer (score 8):

Let $f(x)=\frac  1 {\sqrt x}$ for $0<x<1$ and $0$ for all other $x$. Then $f\in L^{1}$ but $f^{2} \notin L^{1}$.