# $\int_{I}|f(x)||g(x)|^{2}dx \leq \bigg(\int_{I}|f(x)|dx\bigg)\bigg(\int_{I}|g(x)|^{2}dx\bigg)^{\beta}$

Tags: integration, lp-spaces

$f \in L^{1}(I)$ and $g \in L^{2}(I)$. Is it possible to obtain an inequality of type
$$
\int_{I}|f(x)||g(x)|^{2}dx \leq \bigg(\int_{I}|f(x)|dx\bigg)\bigg(\int_{I}|g(x)|^{2}dx\bigg)^{\beta}?
$$
with $|I| < \infty$ and for some $\beta > 0$.

Comment: In the title you have an additional parameter $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank very much. There is not!

Comment: I'd be pleasently surprised if there's a general result of this form given a naive application of Holder makes $\beta \to \infty$.

Comment: This amounts to ask for $\int_{I}|fh| \le\left(\int_I|f|\right)\left(\int_{I}|h|\right)^{\alpha}$ for $f,h\in L^1(I).$

Comment: You need to do a sanity check on any such estimate. The dependence on $f$ and $g$ should scale in the same way on both sides. So I can only imagine this can hold for $\beta=1$ (so it is linear in $f$ and quadratic in $g$ on both sides). Even in this case, it's not clear if it's true; it doesn't follow from Holder, for instance.

Comment: @AnneBauval That. Can I guarantee it's true for some $\beta > 0$?

Comment: @Jeff For $\beta = 1$ can you tell that this is true?

Comment: This is asserting $fh \in L^1$ if both $f$ and $h$ are in $L^1$ as pointed out by Anne Bauval. Therefore, this result is impossible.

Comment: Ok! Thank very much.

Comment: Therefore [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616918/is-the-product-of-l1-functions-l1) is related and the answer is negative

Comment: OK. Thanks to everyone who replied to me.